# How to position Keyboard Tab on new page loaded?

Tags: accessibility

I have a webpage made using Frame. I am doing Accessibility testing using keyboard only. When the keyboard Tab focus on the hyperlink and hitting Enter opening page from another Frame source on the parent page but  Tab Focus is not positioning on the page that is loaded instead it moves in sequence order and moves to that page.

Comment: I think you might need to put the frame id in the href of your link, but it's hard to say without seeing your code. Could you add a code sample to your question?

Comment: Frames are not recommended for use now (except for `<iframe>`s) and are not in the HTML5 specification. Anyway, please show some code.